# Function to find crypto assets robin_stocks

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

I was reading through the [Robin stocks Documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/robin-stocks/downloads/pdf/latest/) and it does not seem to have a way to check the cryptocurrencies you own. The build_holdings() function seems to only work for regular stocks, but seems to omit the cryptocurrencies. Is there another function that works for crypto?

```
>>> my_stocks = robin_stocks.build_holdings()
>>> for key,value in my_stocks.items():
>>> print(key,value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your crypto positions are accessed from a function at the top of page 62 of the documentation: `robin_stocks.robinhood.crypto.get_crypto_positions()`

Example:

```
import robin_stocks.robinhood as r

# login

r.crypto.get_crypto_positions()
```

Note: I have tested that this function returns the correct positions in my account.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how I missed that

Comment: @Jonathan: no worries. It's quite different naming to `build_holdings()`. Happy coding.